# Operation on a Group that isn't stated

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we are given $G = \mathbb{R}$ and the operation isn't explicitly given, is it assumed to be the $+$ operator?

Comment: Probably, but I guess it depends on context.

Comment: YES.  And if they mention a topological property without specifying a topology, it should be assumed to be the usual topology.  And if they mention measure without spedifying which measure, it should be assumed to be Lebesgue measure.  And if they say $\mathbb R$ is a field, without mention of which operations, then assume the usual operations.  Etc.

Comment: Assuming that other context doesn't hint at the possibility of a different group operation: Yes! Or if not, then your teacher is being abusive.

Answer (score 4):

For any odd integer $n$, you can define $a \# b = \sqrt[n]{a^n+b^n}$. This operation on $\mathbb{R}$ makes it a group however, the *usual* operation is addition.

Comment: +1 - nice answer! The OP is referring to the general case - yours is a special case, not used very often.

Comment: Indeed. Hence "the *usual*" - just illustrating that other operations exist.

Comment: The question we were given is G = $\mathbb{R}$, H = $\{\log a| a \in \mathbb{Q}, a > 0\}$; determine if H is a subgroup.  Obviously $0 \not\in H$.

Comment: As remarked by @GEdgar above, the operation in your question **will** be addition. I was just giving an example of some less usual operations one could define! Can you prove/disprove the question with this in mind?

Comment: @spitfiredd $0\in H$!  It is of the form $\log a$ with $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, after all (take $a=1$)...

Comment: Whoops you are correct!!  I even plotted this on an excel spreadsheet and I guess I overlooked it.  Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

This is not just about mathematics; it is  a useful guiding principle, or a thumb rule in the absence of  any other information. See below:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Comment: It could just as easily be multiplication, if you're not acquainted with the restriction that specifying a group by its underlying set requires it to be a group over the whole set.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that is what it would be, although I think I'd say so explicitly.